# Create an axios call that will update state and then perform another one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, axios

I have quite a riddle here . I am trying to perform two  HTTP Axios calls based on one button click . Basically the first will fetch me the right token . I want to update the initial state of the component and then push a second call with the updated state . But it seems that the second call do not wait for the firs one to be finished and that is why my state is not updated and i cannot diplay anything . Can someon give me a hand . I will leave a example of my code here :

```
const [useFetchedToken, setUseFetchedToken] = useState();
const [useFetchedCustomerFromToken, setUseFetchedCustomerFromToken] = useState();

...

  const fetchData = async () => {
     const firstBody= {
           url,
           customer
        };

  const firstHeader = {
         headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
         'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
         'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
           }
          };

   const firstUrl = serverUrl + '/api/view/customer'

   const secondBody = {
          url,
          customer : useFetchedCustomerFromToken,
          startDate,
          endDate
                };

     const secondHeader = {
             headers: {
             'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
             'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
             'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + useFetchedToken
                    }
                };

    const secondUrl= serverUrl + '/api/view/user/invoices'

try {
  const myFirstCall = await axios.post(firstUrl , firstBody, firstHeader)

                    const tokenFromResponse = response.data.token

                    setUseFetchedToken(tokenFromResponse)

                    setUseFetchedCustomerFromToken(jwt_decode(response).customer)

const mySecondCall = await axios.post(secondUrl, secondBody, secondHeader)
...
  }
```

I see that the state gets updated , but i am afraid that no matter that it get updated the call is performed and the right data is not inserted

Answer (score 1):

A few things, but I'll address the problem first.

Your state doesn't get updated immediately, so you can't use a `setState` function and then access `state` immediately after, because it hasn't updated yet. It will be current in a subsequent render. So, you'll need to use the value from your first call directly, not via state. So,

```
const mySecondCall = await axios.post(secondUrl, secondBody, secondHeader)
```

has to be

```
const mySecondCall = await axios.post(secondUrl, 
{
    url,
    // use value, not state
    customer : jwt_decode(response).customer,
    startDate,
    endDate
}, 
{
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        // use value, not state
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + tokenFromResponse
    }
})
```

Then you can set your state like you did *after* this.

The other thing is your state naming conventions. `use` is recommended for naming hooks *only*, so don't do `const [useSomeState, setUseSomeState] = useState("")`

Comment: Okey i see what you mean , but now when the button has been clicked only one call has been performed and this is the `myFirstCall`

Comment: Is the 2nd post happening at all? Does it fail with an error?

Comment: Yes , the first call has been triggered and i have a response with the new token . The message that i see into the console is `InvalidTokenError {message: "Invalid token specified"}
message: "Invalid token specified"`

Comment: @PandaMastr Okay, so the code is called, but there's something wrong with the token/data being passed. Double-check my code. What I gave you is the general idea and should be fairly close. I can't actually run it to test it though. That's where you come in. :)

Comment: i think by you way it does not accept the header and the body and that is why it does not perform the call , because i gave it a try with hardcoded value and i see that the call is performed

Comment: @PandaMastr Is there a value in `tokenFromResponse` or is it empty?

Comment: yes it has the value that is returned from the response or in one word the token

Comment: If what you're hard-coding is the exact same thing as `tokenFromResponse`, I can't begin to guess why that's failing.